# omniauth + devise "user/auth/facebook" magic route question

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

On a rails 3 app, I've got these routes defined:

```
    devise_for :users, :controllers => {:omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks", :registrations => 'registrations'}, :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout' } do
      get 'login' =>'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
      post 'login' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
      get 'signup'  => 'registrations#new', :as => :new_user_registration
      get 'signout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
    end

    # catchall route to deal with routing errors
    match "*path" => "error#index"
```

However, now when I go to log /user/auth/facebook, it routes me to the errors page...

My solution to this was to add constraints to the final match:

```
    match "*path" => "error#index", :constraints => lambda {|req| !req.path.starts_with?("/users/auth/") }
```

This works, but I am wondering if there is a better way... ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are better off letting a 404 page handle routing errors. You only get a 500 error in development. It's a 404 in production. For example on my site: http://agmprojects.com/test. So i suggest using the 404.html in the public folder instead, rather than loading that controller. Out of curiosity, are you responding with a 404 http status code?

Comment: using the static error pages does not enable you to do things such as add partials, and include your application layout...  Yes, the status code is included in the controller action's render call.

Comment: Just ran into this method: http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v3.0.8rc1/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html#M007459 You should be able to catch a RecordNotFound.